# Format an APFS hard disk on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, apfs

I have an internal SSD that was installed on a Mac laptop I owned.

I bought a new Windows laptop and I want to install this SSD on it, but the drive is formatted in APFS. I installed Paragon APFS for Windows, as well as the full 5 days trial of MacDrive utility, but both of them only give the possibility to access the files inside the drive, none of them give the ability to format the disk in NTFS, for example.

Is there any tools that I don't know off that are able to format an APFS on Windows ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps I did to get it done :

1. Launch a new Command Prompt (cmd)
2. Type the command **diskpart**
3. type **list disk** and note the number of the APFS formatted disk
4. type **select disk X** where X is the number noted in step 3
5. type **clean**. Now the drive doesn't have partitions anymore, it's just an unallocated space.
6. Go to Disk Management, by right clicking on the start menu button.
7. Select the unallocated space that corresponds to your drive, right click and Format

Comment: For the record, steps 6-7 could also be done via diskpart using `create partition primary`, `format quick fs=ntfs`, and `assign letter=X`.